# Using InheritanceManager (django-model-utils) on proxy models

Tags: django, django-models, polymorphism

I'm using InheritanceManager from [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) to get the subclass of a given Django model during query:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Generic(models.Model):

    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def template(self):
        return 'Generic.html'

class Specific(Generic):

    def template(self):
        return 'Specific.html'

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

I call

```
Specific.objects.create()
try:
    print Generic.objects.get().template()
    print Specific.objects.get().template()
    print Generic.objects.select_subclasses().get().template()
finally:
    Specific.objects.get().delete()
```

and the output is

```
Generic.html
Specific.html
Generic.html  # <--- why isn't this specific? I'm calling for subclasses.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work when `Specific` is not a proxy?

Comment: Yes, it works. Seems proxy are not supported.

Comment: Wow. Just came across this myself. Proxy is not supported. :( :( :( Have you come across a solution yet?

Comment: Me too. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I filed bug report on Github https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/issues/168